# How to show that this works (complex numbers)

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

So if I have a set of complex numbers:

$A= \{z\in\mathbb{C} |\ \text{Re}\,(z) > 0, |z|<1\}$ 
So I have a problem showing this:

For any $z\in A$ exists $w\in A$ such,that this works:

$z=\frac{1-w}{1+w}$

So I tried using $z=a+bi$  and $w=c+di$, but it did not help much.

So I know I have to apply those information about $z$ and $w$ I have since they are in A.
But I am sadly stuck at that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to show that $w=\frac{1-z}{1+z} \in A$ i.e. that $Re(w)>0$ and $|w|<1$.

Comment: Hm, i don't totally understand..

Comment: For each z exists only one w satisfying your equation. Namely, $w=\frac{1-z}{1+z}$. So you have to show that this w is from A.

Comment: Can you show that $|w|=\left|\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right|<1$?

Comment: Oh i understand now. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:
$$
z = \frac{1-w}{1+w}\\
z(1+w) = 1-w\\
z+zw = 1-w\\
zw + w = 1-z\\
w(1+z) = 1-z\\
w = \frac{1-z}{1+z}
$$
so, given your $z$ you that is how you get your $w$. What's left is to check that this $w$ is actually inside $A$, as long as $z$ is.